# Getting Screen Overflow when populating Column in flutter

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter

I know that we can use a `ListView` or `Expanded` instead of column in such case , but when I use ListView instead of Column , I get a runtime exception for the below code .
The TextFields in the column overflow when the keyboard opens after focusing an input .

```
class _AddAchievementDialog extends State<AddAchievementDialog> {
  String title, description, longDescription, linksString, id;

  List<String> links;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        "Add",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      content: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: 350,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
            ),
            TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: 2,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
            ),
            TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: 3,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Long Description'),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(labelText: 'Links (seperated by comma) '),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Submit"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to wrap `Column` in `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13339) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the Column-Widget inside aScrollView- Widget and adjust some flagsit.

```
ListView(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: <Widget>[
     Text();
  ]
);
```

With those set, you prevent your Widget from showing the overflow- error; furthermore, with the physics set, you prevent the listview from showing the overscroll-ui inside the listview.